# Website host to run independent javascript code?

Tags: javascript, csv, web

I am new to Javascript and was wondering, is there a way to have my server run my javascript code independently from the website? Let's say I am pulling from an API, I would like it to be pulled one time every 5 minutes (avoid calling API multiple times). I will be storing a csv file to write/store to. The csv files will be used by the website to display the data. Also, is there anything wrong with my approach? Thank you ahead of time :)

Comment: You mean the CSV file would serve as cache?

Comment: @JeremyThille correct

Comment: Well, there's nothing wrong with that IMO. If it's quite small, you could also just keep the data in memory, no need to write and read a file.

Comment: @JeremyThille I do plan on writing to a file for a prolonged period of time. I believe that this setup is necessary and the data will accumulate. My only concern is that, I want to setup a javascript program to run alone, not on the website visitors end, but the server end to pull the data. How does that work?

Comment: Well, that's way too broad for Stackoverflow. You're supposed to ask for one specific problem (like a bug etc. with relevant code), not for general orientation. But if you want to run Javascript on your server... NodeJS is definitely the way to go.

Comment: @JeremyThille Ah, I googled but I wasn't searching the correct terms. Thanks for helping me out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are lots of tools for running JavaScript outside of a browser. These days, the most popular one is [Node.js](https://nodejs.org/en/), but others include [Windows Scripting Host](https://legalizeadulthood.wordpress.com/2009/08/30/automating-tasks-with-windows-script-host-and-javascript/) and [Rhino](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Projects/Rhino).

Be aware that the JavaScript language doesn't have very many features and a lot of things you might take for granted are part of browser-specific APIs. Make sure you pay attention to what APIs are provided by the tool you use to execute JavaScript or consider something like [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org) which drives a headless browser.

For the task you describe, you shouldn't need to use anything browser specific. Just be aware that you'll need to use a different library for some things (such as making HTTP requests).

NB: Node.js and other tools for running JS outside the browser aren't typically available on generic, cheap hosting. You'll normally need either specialist hosting packages that explicitly include them, or your own physical or virtual private server. You are more likely to find that a generic hosting package lets you run a PHP script on a cronjob, which could be used to get the result you desire… just without your programming language preference.